# Checking permissions in controller and in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, permissions

I want to create permissions on some actions like creating or updating information (but not for displaying). 
For this I'm adding attributes before all the necessary methods e.g.

```
[Permissions(Permissions.Admin)]
public ActionResult Create()
{
   //...
}
```

Besides I wouldn't like to leave the links active on the index page. So I have to add some checks inside the views.

```
@if (checking...)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")  

}
```

The more checks I add,  the more boring, and the more things I have to keep in my mind. 
How to do it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your could create a HtmlHelper for this.

Something like `@Html.ActionLinkUsingPermissions("Create New", "Create",Permissions.Admin)`

The HtmlHelper would decide whether or not to display the link depending on the current users permissions.

Comment: Yes, it's better than do checking inside a view.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a read-only version of views and letting the controller decides which version it should return (based on your permission).

Shared UI can be then externalized in partial views.

It's recommended to keep your view free from business logic as much as possible.

Comment: I understand this. I want the permissions to be determined by roles. I assume that the roles are different and may consist of different combination of permissions. I want to optimize my code and try to keep it structured. Is there no way to do it except increase the count of views?

Answer (score 1):

You could also create two different view models. One for read/write and one for just read. Then using the [View Templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html) feature you can have one view automatically pick the right template to show using this line:

```
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

Comment: What if I need more than two view models? If for instance the roles will consist of different combination of permissions. Is that good to create as many viewmodels as I need for such kind of operations?

Comment: In that case I would go a different route. That would leave to many models and might not be worth it.